# In Scala can I implement a def with a case class?

Tags: scala

In Scala 2.12, I can implement a nullary method with a case object:

```
trait T[X] {
 def f: X
}

trait XImpl {
 def sayHi: String
}

object O extends T[XImpl] {
 case object f extends XImpl {
  val sayHi = "Hi"
 }
}

> defined trait T
> defined trait XImpl
> defined object O
```

But if I add a method with arguments, and implement it with a case class, it does not work:

```
trait T[X] {
 def f: X
 def g(x: X): X
}

trait XImpl {
 def sayHi: String
}

object O extends T[XImpl] {

 case object f extends XImpl {
  val sayHi = "Hi"
 }

 case class g(x: XImpl) extends XImpl {
  def sayHi = x.sayHi.toUpperCase
 }

}

> error: object creation impossible, since method g in trait T of type (x: XImpl)XImpl is not defined
```

Is there some magic to make it work, or do I have to implement a method that simply instantiates the case class ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `object` behaves like a (lazy) `val`, and that's why it can be used to implement a nullary `def`.

A `case class` is a combination of a `class` and an `object` (and so a `lazy val`), but neither of them can implement a `def` with parameters.

This also means that making your class `implicit` instead of `case` works, because then it defines an `implicit def` with that name as well. But I wouldn't recommend it to solve this problem.

> do I have to implement a method that simply instantiates the case class

Yes. Note that to avoid accidental recursion it needs to be

```
def g(x: XImpl) = new g(x) // or g.apply(x), but not g(x)
```

Answer (score 1):

The thing is that `case class` are not instances.

But to satisfy your trait `T`, you need to ensure that `O` implementing `T[XImpl]` has a property named `g` which confirms to type `XImpl`. And surely your case class `g` does not.

And if you are thinking about the companion object of `g`, then it conforms to the anonymous type `g.type` and will not confirm to `XImpl`.